# What are some good profiling tools for Linux?

Tags: linux, monitoring, software-rec, profiling

I'm looking for some good profiling tools for Linux like [OProfile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net). What I would like to see is how the operating system manages the interrupts, cache, read/writes, etc (lots of other intricate operations inside the OS) for different applications and workloads. Ofcourse, I can select a bunch of different system monitoring tools like sar, iostat, vmstat and what not, but using different type of tools and synchronizing all the data is a pain, especially when you are monitoring cache line, interrupts, etc.

Oprofile gives a nice overview and detailed analysis of what I want, but sometimes it fails to run on the latest kernels. I'm not sure why. But in any case, I would like to know if there is a nice alternative to this?

Comment: Not a good SE answer, but future readers might want to look at this: http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ksar and get graphical input of your sar file output. Moreover,use graphviz and rrdtool to generate graphical information from your input data.Its a one time effort but will be useful for you in long run.

Answer (score 0):

Some tools that might be of interest for you

[perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page)

[kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html)

[latencytop](https://latencytop.org/)

[lttng](https://lttng.org/)

Answer (score 0):

`atop`, particularly recent versions, displays a raft of data on system performance.  Most usefully it can be configured to run as a daemon, logging snapshots of data for future retrieval.  I have it log every 60 seconds and the historic data has been invaluable.